# how to find network connections from a PID

Tags: linux, bash

I have a PID and i am trying to find the network connections that are attached to that PID.

i have placed the pid into a variable $PID.

So far I have tried using netstat to do it. I have tried the following

```
netstat -p | grep $PID
netstat | grep $PID
```

but these do not seem to grep anything or find what im looking for. What would be the best way to find these?

Answer (score 0):

**strace** will do the job:

```
strace -p $PID -f -e trace=network -s 10000
```

`-s 1000` increases the maximum string size to print, which is 32 by default.

[Check out this question on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233490) for alternatives.

Comment: Is there no way you can do this using netstat? I have read the link you sent but I don't understand whats going on

Answer (score 0):

You can also use netstat. Just replace -p with -nap.

> netstat -nap | grep {CMD-of-PID}

its from cmd of pid actually.